# Почему нет значений атрибутов?

Tags: opencart

После переeзда сайта на новый хостинг значения большей части атрибутов у товаров пропали Opencart Версия 2.0.2.0. 
Дамп БД делал в день переноса на новый хостинг. В сохраненой копии страниц в ПС значения атрибутов выведены.
Возможно ли восстановить значения?

Comment: А кеши чистили после переноса?

Comment: Да, через админку и через FTP

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй версию php на 5.6 или 5.4

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]